# is.na(output) || !is.character(output)': 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1) - Error in RStudio

Tags: r

I am using R in version 4.3.1 and RStudio RStudio 2023.09.1+494. In many situaions RStudio throws a error like "

```
'is.na(output) || !is.character(output)':'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)
```

RStudio gives me this error when I want to see objects (use command - view(object) or in searchconsoleR package.

This code works correctly

```
library(searchConsoleR)
scr_auth()

t1 <- search_analytics(
  domena,startDate = "2023-10-21"
  ,endDate = "2023-10-21"
  ,dimensions = c( "page")
)
```

but this throw a error

```
library(searchConsoleR)
scr_auth()

t1 <- search_analytics(
  domena,startDate = "2023-10-21"
  ,endDate = "2023-10-21"
  ,dimensions = c("date", "page")
)
```

my error (bellow)

```
Błąd w poleceniu '!is.null(dimensions) && !dimensions %in% c("date", "country", ':
  'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You show some code that is not responsible for an error and then you show two errors without the code that is responsible for the error. This makes answering your question difficult. Can we assume `output` had three elements inyou first error and `dimensions`had 2 elements in the second error? Please consider writing a minmal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd generally advise to first check for open issues on the project site.

In this case, it is here:

https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/searchConsoleR/issues/82

Install the package from github, and the problem will most likely be solved.